# Is there a gun mod for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Can anyone help me find a gun mod for Minecraft that will work on an SMP (Bukkit) server?

Comment: Flan's Mod works with both client- and server-side installations.

Answer (score 4):

Searching for ["gun mod" on the Minecraft forums](http://www.google.com/search?q=gun%20mod%20site%3Aminecraftforum.net&qscrl=1) brings up a few different results. This should be a good starting point.